# Illustrator text find-and-replace oddity

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm working in Illustrator 2020 with a map file that I brought in from FreeHand. Many of the text objects end with an odd-looking character that, in the FreeHand version, was simply an empty space. I've tried Find and Replace in Illustrator, but it doesn't seem to recognize the empty space after (for example) "Dr ". See screenshot. Suggestions? Thanks[image]

Comment: Copy the glyph from the document and paste it into the find field.

Comment: Already tried that.....nothing happens in the Find field. It doesn't appear to recognize it as anything at all, not even a space.

Comment: Can you make a minimal repeateable problem file?